# Python folium - conditional based class_name for DivIcon

Tags: python, folium

I would like to set the class_name based on some conditions in foium.

I tried:

```
     folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
                  icon = folium.DivIcon(html="<b>" + sp + "</b>",
                                        if role == 'Contractor':
                                            class_name= "mapText-Contractor"
                                        else:
                                            class_name= "mapText"
                                        icon_anchor=(30,5))
                ).add_to(fs)
```

but the console says, that my syntax is invalid.

I found, that some classes can be created, but with no more information:

https://snyk.io/advisor/python/branca/functions/branca.element.MacroElement

Is there any way of making the class_name condition-based?

Comment: If my answer works for your question you can accept it! Thanks! It's appreciated!

Comment: I haven't had the occasion to check it. DOn't worry I will be back as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is due to setting up the if-else block inside the function's arguments.

You can use a *one-liner* if-else expression inside a function's arguments like:

```
folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
    icon = folium.DivIcon(html="<b>" + sp + "</b>",
        class_name = "mapText-Contractor" if role == 'Contractor' else "mapText",
        icon_anchor=(30,5))
    ).add_to(fs)
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. The console says "unexpected intend" underneath which dodn't appear before. Therefore I guess, that something is wrong here, unfortunately.

Comment: Unexpected indent? I kept the same line/spacing indentation as your original code.  I'll edit my answer now, I just ran it and it worked fine without raising any errors. It's just the line indentation then.

Comment: Yes, it is, but when I occur an error such as this, which didn't occur earlier, then something is wrong.

Comment: Try using now that I edited it. Your original code's indentation was off, I adjusted the indentation and the one-liner if-else expression works fine as an argument.